# How decode works in CCA1 scheme based on MP12 construction?

Tags: encryption, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, trapdoor, cca1

In Section 6.3 from [MP12](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/efftrap.pdf) we have that $encode(m) = Sm$, for $S$ any basis of $\Lambda(G^t)$. Then I have:

$S = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 64 & 128 & 256\\
2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 64 & 128 & 256 & 0\\
4 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 64 & 128 & 256 & 0 & 0\\
8 & 16 & 32 & 64 & 128 & 256 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
16 & 32 & 64 & 128 & 256 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
32 & 64 & 128 & 256 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
64 & 128 & 256 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
128 & 256 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
256 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

I used very simple parameters: $q=512$, $k=9$, $n=1$, $m=18$. I set $H$ and $R$ to the identity matrix.This way I have that $A_u = [A' \mid -A' + G]$. 
Therefore, I have that $encode([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256] = G$. Fixing $s=1$, I computed $2s.A_u + e + encode(m) = [2.A' \mid -2A' +  2.G] + [0 \mid G] + e = [2.A' \mid -2A' + 3.G] + e \pmod{2q}$.

The inversion oracle returns $z=3$ and a big error $e'$ (but such that $e'.[R \mid I]^t = e.[R \mid I]^t \pmod{q}$). The decryption algorithm returns $m=[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]$.

In general I have that $m$ is being added to $2s$, so the decryption algorithm returns the binary decomposition of $DecimalRepresentation(m)+2s$, instead of only $m$.

In Lemma 6.2, we have that $v^t.[R \mid I]^t = 2(sG \pmod{q}) + encode(m) \pmod{2q}$. Therefore I reached this point successfully. Hence I guess my Decode algorithm is wrong. In order to decode, I am multiplying by $Inverse(S)$. Afterwards I divide the obtained vector by $q^{k-1}$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. In this site, $\LaTeX / MathJax$ is enabled. You can click [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/78062/edit) and edit your question.

Comment: Are you sure about your basis $S$? Do you have $G = I \otimes g$?

Comment: Since $n=1$, then $G = g^t = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]$. I am not sure about basis $S$. I tried
$S = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: But in this case we have that $encode(m) = [2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]$, which gets mixed with error $e$. 
Therefore message $m$ either gets mixed with $s$ or with $e$.

Comment: If you think everything is right up to the decoding step, it might be worthwhile to look at [section 5](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/946.pdf) of that paper. They generalize the decoding step to other moduli, and give explicit algorithms for decoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I revisited the problem and found out that before decoding it is necessary to reduce modulo the fundamental region to find a coset, then we have that in the example I gave the internal value $2s+m$ is equal to $[1, 1, \dots]$, and after reduction it turns out to be equivalent to $[1, 0, \dots]$, which is $m$, as needed.